# Javascript Regex comma separated text

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

**I have this string:**

`remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820,remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820`

I want to match and extract strings separated with commas.

**The result should be:**

```
MATCH 1 
'remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL' 
MATCH 2 
'remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills' 
MATCH 3 
'395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820' 
MATCH 4 
'remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL' 
MATCH 5 
'remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills' 
MATCH 6 
'395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820'
```

**I have this regex:**

```
(remote:[a-zA-Z]+\|[^\,]+|[a-f0-9]{32})
```

but those cities which have state 'AL' (separated with comma) are separated incorrectly.

**Possible solution:**

I was thinking of doing something like this - `remote:[a-zA-Z]+\|.*`  - and end match on the comma which have after it self (`remote:[a-zA-Z]+\|.*`) or md5 hash (`[a-f0-9]{32},?`).

Here is my regex tester link:

https://regex101.com/r/rP8iJ2/1

Comment: Instead of regex, try `line.split(",")`. Trust me, it's not worth parsing a CSV with regex

Comment: @vlaz it wont produce the result i want.. it will output remote:City|Vestavia Hills and AL as two diffent results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single regex you might do as follows;

```js
var str = "remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820,remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820",
    arr = str.match(/(r.+?|[\da-f]{32})(?=,?(remote|[\da-f]{32}|$))/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: masterpiece ! exactly based on my idea :P

Comment: @mwebber I am glad that i could be in help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can fine-tune your regex into this lookahead based regex:

```
/(?:^|,)(.+?(?=,(?:[a-f0-9]{32}|remote:)|$))/igm
```

This will give 6 captured groups as you're expecting.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP8iJ2/2)

```
(?:^|,)                 # Match line start or comma
(                       # captured group #1 start
   .+?                  # match 1 or more of any character (lazy)
   (?=                  # lookahead start
      ,                 # match comma followed by
      (?:               # non-capturing group start
         [a-f0-9]{32}   # match hex digit 32 times
         |              # OR
         remote:        # match literal "remote:"
      )                 # non-capturing group end
      |                 # OR
      $                 # line end
   )                    # looakehad end
)                       # capturing group #1 end
```

Comment: last question, why it does produce - `["remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL", ",remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills", ",395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820", ",remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL", ",remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills", ",395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820"]` (have commas starting on some of them?)

Comment: If you use `exec` in a `while` loop and grab captured group #1 then it will not have starting comma. Even regex101 demo link has that JS code generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-f0-9]{32}|remote:[^|]+\|[^,]+(?:,[A-Z]{2})?),?
```

This one is simpler to understand, I made a special optional sufix to the group, than can only be 2 uppcase letters after a comma.

https://regex101.com/r/rP8iJ2/3

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use split of javascript:

```js
var str = "remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820,remote:City|Vestavia Hills,AL,remote:Citystate|Vestavia Hills,395b5231539390675a7abe0751fc4820";
var aux = str.split("remote");
var res = [];
for (var i=1 ; i < aux.length ; i++){
 res.push("remote" + aux[i]);
};
console.log(res);
```

Comment: does not produce the result i want